# How to apply a Views filter to show fields if a radio button is not FALSE?

Tags: views

I have a custom field that is a radio button (from CiviCRM), and I made it available as a filter by implementing `hook_views_data()`.

I'd like to apply a filter to show fields if the radio button is set to *true*; in other words, `if not == false`.

I feel like this should be possible without using the Views PHP module, but I have hit a wall.

Answer (score 1):

Often these kind of things come back to deciding how best to bend your requirements to suit the available logic. If I understand correctly, you have a radio button with the value of true, but no other options.

My immediate thought is to change it from a radio to a checkbox and set a default value as false (unchecked).

That way you just need to check for if true or if false and you don't need to concern yourself with *if not false* which does get tricky.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good idea in hindsight. Actually the radio button has 2 options: "yes" and "no". Even setting a radio button default or making it "required" would fix future data entries. Unfortunately, the form and data already exist, so changing it would be a pain. It might be the least painful option though...